# CIS benchmark does not pass host configuration test

Tags: linux, docker, linux-audit

After adding below audit rules for docker artifacts:

```
$ sudo auditctl -l
-w /usr/bin/dockerd -p rwxa -k docker
-w /var/lib/docker -p rwxa -k docker
-w /etc/docker -p rwxa -k docker
-w /lib/systemd/system/docker.service -p rwxa -k docker
-w /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket -p rwxa -k docker
-w /etc/default/docker -p rwxa -k docker
-w /etc/docker/daemon.json -p rwxa -k docker
-w /usr/bin/docker-containerd -p rwxa -k docker
-w /usr/bin/docker-runc -p rwxa -k docker
$
```

---

CIS benchmark utility(https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security) does nto pass:

```
$ sudo ./docker-bench-security.sh -c tests/1_host_configuration.sh 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Docker Bench for Security v1.3.5
#
# Docker, Inc. (c) 2015-
#
# Checks for dozens of common best-practices around deploying Docker containers in production.
# Inspired by the CIS Docker Benchmark v1.2.0.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Initializing Wed Sep 11 15:21:04 CST 2019


[INFO] Checks: 0
[INFO] Score: 0
$
```

---

How to pass below audit?

```
[WARN] 1.2.1 - Ensure a separate partition for containers has been created
[INFO] 1.2.2  - Ensure only trusted users are allowed to control Docker daemon
[INFO]        * docker:x:130:mohet01-ubuntu
[WARN] 1.2.3  - Ensure auditing is configured for the Docker daemon
[WARN] 1.2.4  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /var/lib/docker
[WARN] 1.2.5  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /etc/docker
[WARN] 1.2.6  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - docker.service
[WARN] 1.2.7  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - docker.socket
[WARN] 1.2.8  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /etc/default/docker
[INFO] 1.2.9  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /etc/sysconfig/docker
[INFO]        * File not found
[INFO] 1.2.10  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /etc/docker/daemon.json
[INFO]         * File not found
[WARN] 1.2.11  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /usr/bin/containerd
[WARN] 1.2.12  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /usr/sbin/runc
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04` and I have added all the rules in `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` file and it is working fine.

For `CentOS 6`, file is at `/etc/audit/audit.rules`.

```
[INFO] 1.2 - Linux Hosts Specific Configuration
[WARN] 1.2.1 - Ensure a separate partition for containers has been created
[INFO] 1.2.2  - Ensure only trusted users are allowed to control Docker daemon
[INFO]        * docker:x:999:delta
[PASS] 1.2.3  - Ensure auditing is configured for the Docker daemon
[PASS] 1.2.4  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /var/lib/docker
[PASS] 1.2.5  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /etc/docker
[PASS] 1.2.6  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - docker.service
[PASS] 1.2.7  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - docker.socket
[PASS] 1.2.8  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /etc/default/docker
[INFO] 1.2.9  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /etc/sysconfig/docker
[INFO]        * File not found
[INFO] 1.2.10  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /etc/docker/daemon.json
[INFO]         * File not found
[WARN] 1.2.11  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /usr/bin/containerd
[INFO] 1.2.12  - Ensure auditing is configured for Docker files and directories - /usr/sbin/runc
[INFO]         * File not found
```